# How do I grab content based on an outside tag match?

Tags: ruby, arrays, nokogiri

I am trying to organize a list of links and names based on a tag that is outside of the group of where the links and name reside. It's setup like so:

```
<h4>Volkswagen</h4>
<ul>
   <li><a href="http://beetle.cars.com">beetle</a></li>
</ul>

<h4>Chevy</h4>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://volt.cars.com">Volt / Electric</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I need is the result to be in the following format with the name as a link eventually but I can do that later if I can just get the items organized properly.

Each car brand could have multiple models of varying counts. I would need to organize them by car brand:

```
Volkswagen
   Beetle Link  Beetle
   Jetta Link   Jetta

Chevy
   Volt Link  Volt / Electric
   S10 Link  S10
```

I can get the list of brands with no problem. I am just having a hard time associating the batch of models with each brand as the `<h4>` tags aren't nested so I don't know how to associate them with the following `<ul>` list of cars.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to dive straight to each car, then back out to extract the car's brand:

```rb
cars = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }

doc.xpath('//ul/li/a').each do |car|
  brand = car.at('../../preceding-sibling::h4[1]').text
  cars[brand] << {link: car['href'], name: car.text}
end
```

Note that the hash is initialized with a block specifying that the default value is an array. This allows appending hashes (via `<<`) as shown. The XPath `../../preceding-sibling::h4[1]` says: go back up to the `ul` level and look back to the first preceding `h4`. This is the corresponding brand for the car.

Output:

```rb
{"Volkswagen"=>[
                {:link=>"http://beetle.cars.com", :name=>"beetle"}
                # others here
               ],
 "Chevy"=>[
           {:link=>"http://volt.cars.com", :name=>"Volt / Electric"}
           # others here
          ]
}
```

I find this technique nice and simple, with just a single loop. Not everyone likes this style though.